# Windows Azure : Storage Client Exception Unhandled

Tags: c#, azure, exception, azure-blob-storage

I am writing a code for upload large files into the blobs using blocks... When I tested it, it gave me an StorageClientException

It stated: One of the request inputs is out of range.

I got this **exception** in this line of the code:

```
blob.PutBlock(block, ms, null);
```

Here is my code:

```
protected void ButUploadBlocks_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            // store upladed file as a blob storage
            if (uplFileUpload.HasFile)
            {
                name = uplFileUpload.FileName;
                byte[] byteArray = uplFileUpload.FileBytes;
                Int64 contentLength = byteArray.Length;
                int numBytesPerBlock = 250 *1024; // 250KB per block
                int blocksCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)contentLength / numBytesPerBlock);  // number of blocks 
                MemoryStream ms ;
                List<string>BlockIds = new List<string>();
                string block;
                int offset = 0;

                // get refernce to the cloud blob container
                CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("documents");

                // set the name for the uploading files
                string UploadDocName = name;

                // get the blob reference and set the metadata properties
                CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(UploadDocName);
                blob.Properties.ContentType = uplFileUpload.PostedFile.ContentType;

                for (int i = 0; i < blocksCount; i++, offset = offset + numBytesPerBlock)
                {
                    block = Convert.ToBase64String(BitConverter.GetBytes(i));
                    ms = new MemoryStream();
                    ms.Write(byteArray, offset, numBytesPerBlock);

                    blob.PutBlock(block, ms, null);
                    BlockIds.Add(block);
                }

                blob.PutBlockList(BlockIds);

                blob.Metadata["FILETYPE"] = "text";
            }
        }
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve it...

Comment: Do you get the exception on the first call to PutBlock, or after several blocks have been uploaded?  Like, blocks 0-9 upload fine, but block 10 gives the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to do ms.Position = 0 to get the stream back to the start before uploading it.  (Otherwise, presumably PutBlock tries to read from the stream and finds it already at the end.)